# Popup not working on click

Tags: c#, xamarin

I had a listview that when i did a long click it added that item to my database but want to switch it to a popup.

I followed the xamarin docs online but when I click on the listview item it does nothing when it should give two options, either, Follow or Don't Follow.

```
    public void EListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = new PopupMenu(this, eListView.GetChildAt(e.Position));
        popup.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SEMenu);
        popup.MenuItemClick += (s, a) =>
        {
            switch (a.Item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.FollowEvent:
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "TEST follow", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
                case Resource.Id.DontFollowEvent:
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "TEST dont follow", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
                default:
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "An error has occured, please try again.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                break;
            }
        };
    }
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--For all properties see: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html-->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/FollowEvent" android:title="Follow Event" showAsAction="always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/DontFollowEvent" android:title="Don't Follow Event" showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: what happens when you place breakpoints and step thru the code using the debugger..?

Comment: It hits popup.MenuItemClick but doesn't hit the Switch below

Comment: I just added `popup.show();` and it seems to work now. Going to do a few tests on it now.